# Case statement with Sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to identify all IDs from T1 for which T2 has order category of Veggie/Fruits but were *never* distributed. Also any IDs that do not have an order of Veggie/Fruits as well. How should I be doing this?

```
T1:
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

```
T2
T2.ID  Category  Date Ordered    Date Distributed   T1.ID
01     Veggie    01-Jan-2018     01-Jan-2018        1
02     Fruits    02-Jan-2018     03-Jan-2018        1
03     Veggie    01-Jan-2018                        2
04     Nuts      05-Jan-2018     05-Jan-2018        2
05     Fruits    10-Jan-2018                        3
06     Seeds     10-Jan-2018     10-Jan-2018        3
07     Veggie    08-Jan-2018                        4
08     Veggie    11-Jan-2018     11-Jan-2018        5
09     Veggie    20-Jan-2018                        5
10     Fruit     12-Jan-2018     12-Jan-2018        5
11     Fruit     25-Jan-2018                        5
12     Nuts      15-Jan-2018     15-Jan-2018        6
13     Seeds     20-Jan-2018     22-Jan-2018        6
14     Nuts      18-Jan-2018                        7
```

I used a case statement with sum but I am not getting the desired result, the records like T1.2 and T1.3 are being dropped from my result. how should I be correcting my code?

```
select t1.id,
case when sum (
      case when t2.category in ('Veggie','Fruits') and t2.date_distributed is null
      then 0
      else 1 end)<1
then 1
else 0
end
```

Desired Output:

```
2
3
4
6
7
```

Answer (score 3):

If I follow the logic correctly, `exists` comes to mind:

```
select *
from t1
where exists (select 1
              from t2
              where t2.id = t1.id and
                    t2.category in ('Veggie','Fruits') and
                    t2.date_distributed is null
             ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and
                        t2.category in ('Veggie','Fruits') 
                 ) ;
```

EDIT:

I misread the data due to the original formatting of the question.  For your question, I'll follow the same approach:

```
select *
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.t1_id = t1.id and
                        t2.category in ('Veggie','Fruits') and
                        t2.date_distributed is not null
                 ) ;
```

You seem to want `t1.id`s where that are not in the specified categories with a distribution date.

Comment: Hello, sorry after testing this logic I realized I did not post the question correctly, I have updated the question, would you please take a look?

Comment: @skn . . . That is one more condition.

Comment: yes, sorry, I think I missed to replicate the data correctly when I mocked it up. That was why I tried to use the case statement with sum but I did not seem to get the logic correctly.

Comment: Is Case When not an accurate command to use in this scenario?

Comment: @skn . . . You are asking to filter ids, which suggests a `where` clause.  I don't advocate using `case` expressions in a `where` clause, unless you specifically require the guarantee of sequential evaluation.

Comment: the where exists clause is returning #5 - it is not part of my desired result. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

By joining the 2 tables and filtering:

```
select distinct t1.id from t1 inner join t2
on t2.t1id = t1.id
where
  (t2.category in ('Veggie','Fruits') and t2.date_distributed is null)
  or
  (t2.category not in ('Veggie','Fruits'));
```

It is not clear in t2 table what the name of the column containing the id from t1 is so I used `t2.t1id`

Comment: Hello, sorry after testing this logic I realized I did not post the question correctly, I have updated the question, would you please take a look?

Comment: These *any IDs* would be fetched regardless if of the value of `date_distributed`?

Comment: Only Ids with no order of Veggie/Fruit ever placed or ever distributed.

Comment: This **doesn't work as expected**, as 1) it returns duplicated records (e.g. for 6) and 2) wrong records (e.g. for 5). You can't simulate exists / not exists with join, this is the reason why Oracle implements semi and anit join.

Comment: Have you heard about distinct?

Comment: Yes, the query is *distinctly* wrong, you can't get rid of the ID 5 with `select distinct`. Simply try it and see the result with the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want `ID`s for which **doesn't exists** distributed Veggie or Fruits.

So you use `NOT EXISTS` and in the subquery you consider only the records in the categories with `date_distributed is NOT null`

```
select *
from t1
where NOT exists (select null
              from t2
              where t2.t1id = t1.id and
                    t2.category in ('Veggie','Fruits') and
                    t2.date_distributed is NOT null
             );

        ID
----------
         2
         3
         4
         6
         7
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can make use of `Not Exists` logic by `multiplication` of two terms ;*

1. `decode(Category,'Veggie',1,'Fruits',1,0)` is `Zero`, i.e. `Not Veggie/Fruits` **or**
2. `nvl2(Date_Distributed,1,0)` is `Zero`(*null*), i.e. `Not Distributed`

   ```
   with T2( T2_ID, Category, Date_Distributed, T1_ID ) as
   (
    select '01','Veggie', date'2018-01-01', 1 from dual union all   
    select '02','Fruits', date'2018-01-03', 1 from dual union all   
    select '03','Veggie',      null       , 2 from dual union all   
    select '04','Nuts'  , date'2018-01-05', 2 from dual union all   
    select '05','Fruits',      null       , 3 from dual union all   
    select '06','Seeds' , date'2018-01-10', 3 from dual union all    
    select '07','Veggie',      null       , 4 from dual union all   
    select '08','Veggie', date'2018-01-11', 5 from dual union all   
    select '09','Veggie',      null       , 5 from dual union all   
    select '10','Fruit' , date'2018-01-12', 5 from dual union all   
    select '11','Fruit' ,      null       , 5 from dual union all   
    select '12','Nuts'  , date'2018-01-15', 6 from dual union all   
    select '13','Seeds' , date'2018-01-22', 6 from dual union all   
    select '14','Nuts'  ,      null       , 7 from dual 
   )
   select T1_ID       
     from T2 
    group by T1_ID
    having sum(decode(Category,'Veggie',1,'Fruits',1,0)*nvl2(Date_Distributed,1,0))=0
    order by T1_ID;

   T1_ID
   -----
     2
     3
     4
     6
     7
   ```

*By the way, there's no need any join with `T1`. If you want to use the table `T1`, the line `from T2` can be replaced with `from T1 join T2 on T1.ID = T2.T1_ID`.*

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/YYHW53276)</kbd>

Comment: Very unconventional solution, that can be rewritten using `CASE` as requested - `having sum(case when category in ('Veggie','Fruits') and date_distributed is NOT null then 1 else 0  end)=0` +1 also for popularizing `NVL2`:)